# List Item Filtering for Adminsitrators

Tags: 2013, filter, rest

I have a list that I'm querying using RESTful uris like so:

```
http://site/_api/lists/getByTitle('Links')/items
```

Each item in the list has individual permissions applied to it (both users, and groups) so that only certain users have access to certain items.  This works great for normal users, however if an administrator goes to view the list, *all* of the list items show because, well, (s)he's an administrator.

Is there a way to filter the results explicitly by the list item's permissions, using the RESTful uri?

Something like:

```
http://site/_api/lists/getByTitle('Links')/items?$filter=[currentUser] in itemAccessColumn
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Is there logic behind which items are assigned? you could filter based on that if it exists.

Comment: Not really. Some permissions are assigned by hand, others are assigned based on the user that created them.